# Expression for sum over paths

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, definition, path-integral

In an introductory lecture on the path integral formalism, I came across the following. Suppose that $\gamma$'s are paths such that a particle travelling along any of them reaches the position co-ordinate (for simplicity, take it to be 1-d) $q_f$ at time $t_f$ from its initial state $(q_i, t_i)$. Every path $\gamma$ is broken into a series of points $(q_0, t_0), (q_1, t_1), \ldots, (q_N, t_N)$ where $(q_0, t_0) = (q_i, t_i)$ and $(q_N, t_N) = (q_f, t_f)$ and the time-steps are linear, as shown in the figure below.
[image]

Then it was essentially stated that for any functional $f$ which takes in a path $\gamma$ as and spits out a number $f(\gamma)$, the following holds 
$$\sum_{\text{all paths }\gamma}f(\gamma) \stackrel{?_1}= \int f(\gamma) dy_1~dy_2~\ldots~dy_{N-1} \stackrel{?_2}=\int\mathcal{D}q(t) f(\gamma)$$

I understand that if we fix $(t_0, t_1, \ldots, t_N)$, then sum over all the paths will essentiall be the sum over all the possible combinations of $(q_1, \ldots, q_{N-1})$ ($q_0$ and $q_N$ are fixed). But still I'm unable to "see" why $?_1$ follows as to why it takes the form of an integral. Can you please explain?

Also, for $?_2$, I have no idea what on earth $\mathcal{D}(t)$ represents and why it has the parameter $t$. It was briefly uttw=ered that this was some measure and the integral was a Lebesgue integral. But I've never had any experience with this before. Hence, can you explain these intuitively to me, brushing off the mathematical details under the carpet?

Comment: [Near](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3581810/) duplicate.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks Cosmas, it helped!